# When training a neural network, should you pass all of the training data to the network in one go?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, training-data

I feel as if this is something covered in NN 101, but I can't remember the answer (if there is one) and can't seem to find an answer on the web.

Say I have a training set of 80 items and test set of 20 items. I've initialised the weights and biases on my neural network and am now ready to train the network to understand the general trend in the data.

Do I:

a) Pass all 80 items into the network at once, find the error, use backprop to adjust weights and bias in the direction of the gradient, repeat until error is small enough.

or

b) Pass in 1 item into the network, find the error, use backprop to adjust weights and bias in the direction of the gradient, repeat for the other 79 items, and then start the process again from item #1 until error is small enough.

or even choose a number between 1-80.

In my web searches I found something called online and batch training, I have a feeling it's related to this, but am not completely sure. Is there an advantage to choosing one method over the other?

Answer (score 0):

You chose everyone option. If you pass all samples and than adapt you doing batch learning, if you adapt after everyone sample you doing minibatch learning. My teacher recommend me using stochastic gradient descent approach.

Pros and cons of both are nicely explained there [SG vs BL](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49528/batch-gradient-descent-versus-stochastic-gradient-descent)

Also, if you use adapt after some part of dataset, you doing mini batch learning. In this approach is problematic determinate size the dataset part.